# Shared instance with global variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, singleton, global-variables

Thanks to some previous questions I managed to share global variables in my whole application.

But still I'm wondering if what I've done is a good practice :

**GlobalVariables.h**

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventType;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *docType;

   // Getters of properties
   + (NSMutableArray *) eventType;
   + (NSMutableArray *) docType;
```

**GlobalVariables.m**

```
@implementation GlobalVariables

+ (id)sharedInstance {
   static GlobalVariables *instance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   // Assert that only one instance of this class will be created
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       instance = [[GlobalVariables alloc] init];
       // Default values for our shared variables
       NSArray *defaultEvents = @[@"Default",@"Reunion",@"Famille",@"Vacances"];
       NSArray *defaultDocs = @[@"Handwritten Document",@"Business Card",@"Whiteboard",@"Invoice",@"Picture",@"Printed Document",@"Table",@"To Note"];
       [instance setEventType:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:defaultEvents]];
       [instance setDocType:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:defaultDocs]];
   });
   return instance;
}

// Getter of eventType property
+ (NSMutableArray *) eventType {
   GlobalVariables *instance = [GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
   return instance.eventType;
}

// Getter of docType property
+ (NSMutableArray *) docType {
   GlobalVariables *instance = [GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
   return instance.docType;
}

// Add a new document type to docType property
+ (void)addNewDocType:(NSString*)doc {
   GlobalVariables *instance = [GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
   [instance.docType addObject:doc];
}
```

As you can see I call `sharedInstance:` in my getters (and other methods), this way I can access (and modify) my global variables in any other class like this :

**OtherClass.m**

```
NSMutableArray *types = [GlobalVariables docType];
...
[GlobalVariables addNewDocType:@"Slide"];
```

Is it acceptable or not ? 
I know I could get these variables this way :

**OtherClass.m**

```
GlobalVariables *sharedVariables = [GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
NSMutableArray *types = [sharedVariables docType];
...
[sharedVariables addNewDocType:@"Slide"];
```

But it would mean that any other class using these variables should have a GlobalVariables attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, what you have is not a global variable, it is a singleton. Its name, `GlobalVariables`, is not very descriptive, though. Since singletons in iOS applications are often used to make a model, good chances are that your `GlobalVariables` could be renamed to `Model`.

Next, you could minimize the need to call `[Model instance]` by making an instance variable in other classes where `Model` is used (although this is not necessary - it's only a convenience). But there is an alternative plan that may work as well: add *class* methods to `Model` that retrieve events and doc types, like this:

```
+(NSMutableArray*) eventType {
    return [Model instance].eventType;
}
+(NSMutableArray*) docType {
    return [Model instance].docType;
}
```

This would shorten the code as well, and perhaps make it more readable by eliminating an additional level of indirection.

Comment: Clear explanation of the difference between model and global variables. Thanks